# Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined nodejs|Pug

Tags: node.js, pug

Describe the bug

Node.js version: v14.1.0
OS & version: macOS clatina

When trying to make a call currentPath.startsWith(item.slug) in my pug file I got this error.

Actual behavior
TypeError: /Users/maruf/www/sites/storify/views/layout.pug:18

Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined at eval (eval at wrap (/Users/maruf/www/sites/storify/node_modules/pug-runtime/wrap.js:6:10), :44:92)

Expected behavior
Don't throw error

Comment: Probably something you might want to report to the developers of Pug.

Comment: Can you share the `layout.pug` file the error refers to?

Comment: each item in h.menu
              li.nav__item
                a.nav__link(href=item.slug, class=(currentPath.startsWith(item.slug) ? 'nav__link--active' : ''))
                  != h.icon(item.icon)
                  span #{item.title}

Comment: @AhmedMaruf this code doesn't mean much in a comment. Can you edit your question to include it?